# In Perforce how can I move files on a stream to a different depot?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I wish to move some files in a Perfore depot to a different depot. The depots are set up to use perforce streams.

So from
`//Depot1/stream/directory`
to 
`//Depot2/stream/directory`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've found one way using copy below but it seems overly complex. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use copy.

- Create a workspace for Depot2 and tie it to the destination stream.
- In P4V select 'copy'
- In the source enter `//Depot1/stream/directory` and in the destination `//Depot2/stream/directory`
- Select copy then submit.
- Then in a separate workspace tied to the source stream in Depot1, mark the files for delete and submit these changes separately.

Comment: This is the best way.  Using the "move" command isn't permitted because move is an atomic operation, and you can't split an atom across two different streams.